# Как вырезать кусок из изображения в отдельный файл?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Как можно, используя стандартные библиотеки, вырезать кусок из изображения с заданными координатами в отдельный файл?
Заранее спасибо!

```
static List<Image> ReadTilesFromTilesList(string pathToImage, int tileSize, int borderSize)        
{
    var output = new List<Image>();
    var map = new Bitmap(pathToImage);
    //var columns = map.Width + borderSize/tileSize + borderSize;
    //var rows = map.Height + borderSize/tileSize + borderSize;
    //var ppi = rows*columns;

    for (var i = 0; i <= map.Height; i += tileSize + borderSize)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j <= map.Width; j +=tileSize + borderSize)
        {
            Image t = new Bitmap(tileSize, tileSize);
            //Graphics.FromImage(map).DrawImage(t, new Rectangle(j, i, tileSize, tileSize), new Rectangle(0, 0, tileSize, tileSize), GraphicsUnit.Pixel); - exception индексированные пиксели
            t = map.Clone(new Rectangle(j, i, tileSize, tileSize), PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed); // - exception недостаточно памяти
            output.Add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мое нетривиальное решение выдает ошибку: "Невозможно создать объект графики из изображения, имеющего индексированный формат пикселей".

Comment: дык покажите решение

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Гугле по запросу "crop image c#" [первой ссылкой выдает то, что нужно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c).